# Why is the identity predicate needed?

Tags: logic, identity, predicate-logic

In *Logic: The Laws of Truth* the identity predicate is introduced as an extension of general predicate logic (GPL). The following propositions are given as motivating examples:

(1) "Mark Twain is Samuel Langhorne Clemens."

(2) "Mark Twain is a novelist."

Smith says that while (2) can be translated into GPL, (1) cannot. This is because the "is" in (2) expresses predication (i.e. it is part of the predicate "is a novelist"), whereas the "is" in (1) expresses *identity* (in this case that Mark Twain and Samuel Langhorne Clemens are one and the same person). GPL has no way of expressing identity and therefore, cannot express the proposition in (1).

To remedy this, the syntax of GPL is augmented with the identity predicate, giving us [general predicate logic with identity](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=wlL2GHt1gS8C&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=%22is+meant+to+express+the+relation+of+identity%22&source=bl&ots=ZzrICZ--hS&sig=ACfU3U1NtTATWATI-ukyuqqHZGOOXTfjPQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKq-6X_L2CAxUtklYBHVF1CwUQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22is%20meant%20to%20express%20the%20relation%20of%20identity%22&f=false) (GPLI). Given the glossary `m: Mark Twain; s: Samuel Langhorne Clemens`, (1) can now be translated into GPLI as `m = s`.

**However, it's not clear to me *why* (1) cannot be adequately translated into GPL. Couldn't we set up the following dictionary:**

```
m: Mark Twain
Sx: x is Samuel Langhorne Clemens
```

**and translate (1) into GPL simply as `Sm`?** We can think of the name *m* as picking out the individual referred to by the name "Mark Twain" and the extension of `Sx` as the set of objects containing that same individual, so that `Sm` is true. **What is wrong with this approach?**

The distinction between the "is" of predication and the "is" of identity seems to be attributed to Frege (I think the English translation of the paper is *On Concept and Object*?), but I'm not able to understand the gist of his arguments.

Comment: You will have to duplicate every proper name by a predicate, and then add rules connecting predicates to their names that duplicate properties of identity, like substitution and transitivity. A single predicate dispenses with all of that. And it also lets you identify quantified variables, which your procedure does not cover.

Comment: Thanks @Conifold. When you say we'd need extra rules, do you mean postulates such as `Mx ⟷ Sx` (where `Mx: x is Mark Twain; Sx: x is Samuel Clemens`) to establish symmetry, so that if we know `Mx`, then we can infer `Sx` (just as if we know `m = s`, then we can infer `s = m`)?

Answer (score 11):

The standard approach in predicate logic is to use names to identify things, and predicates to identify properties. Samuel Clemens is a name, not a property.

It is possible to do as you suggest and use a predicate as a combination of properties that identify a thing. One way to do this would be to treat names as definite descriptions and use Russell's theory of definite descriptions. Quine advocated this approach. Alternatively, we could think of Mx as "x has the property of being called Mark Twain". This approach is sometimes referred to as predicativism or even "being-called predicativism". Both have been debated in the literature of philosophical logic (e.g. references 1 and 2 below).

Potentially these approaches allow us to eliminate names altogether. But it would be incongruent to use Mark Twain as a name and Samuel Clemens as a predicate. If you really wanted to go down this route, a better option would be to treat both as predicates and write their identity as:

(∃x)(Mx ∧ Sx)

The problem then is that this says there is at least one thing that is both Mark Twain and Samuel Clemens. To express uniqueness you would want to write something like:

(∃x)((Mx ∧ Sx) ∧ (∀y)((My ∨ Sy) → (x = y)))

Notice how we still need the identity relation. We can't escape from it: it's just too useful. This is why *Logic: The Laws of Truth* says that we need identity to express sentences like, There are two dogs, or, There are between ten and twenty dogs (page 299).

Using names in the standard way is more convenient because it is built into the calculus that a name has a unique referent, so it is much simpler to write:

s = m

Another drawback of identifying individuals using a predicate is that the identity relation has properties that we usually take to hold universally: it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive. So, for example, from s = m together with m = b we can infer s = b. If we wished to use predicates instead, we would have to write these relations out in full. Not impossible, just extra work.

1. Delia Graff Fara, "Names Are Predicates", Philosophical Review, Vol. 124, 2015, pp 59-117.
2. Michael Rieppel, "Quinean Predicativism". Philosophical Studies, Vol. 178, 2021, pp. 23-44.

Comment: Thank you @Bumble. Would object anonymity be another reason that necessitates the identity predicate? In the example in [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/104911/62633), the objects in the domain (the `y`s) don't have names, so the approach proposed in my post falls apart as we wouldn't even be able to create the name predicates. (I don't know if that means that it is impossible to express the claim of injectivity in plain GPL though?)

Comment: Potentially, yes. One might wish to say that there is a single individual that is both King of the UK and King of Australia, without naming him. You would need the identity predicate to express uniqueness. Also, you might want to express a general principle such as "everything is identical with itself" which would be tricky to write in first order logic without an identity predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: the answer below address the question whether the identity predicate is needed in first-order logic. On re-reading the OP's post, that might not have been exactly what they were asking.

Yes, you can express the proposition "Mark Twain is S. L. Clemens" as "S(m)" if you like. This trades a single binary predicate symbol for many unary predicates (perhaps infinitely many). But just because you eliminated this particular use of equality does not at all mean that you have shown that we can eliminate all uses of equality.

Suppose you want to say that a real-valued function f: R→R is injective (i.e. distinct inputs yield distinct outputs). With equality, this is simple: the proposition "f is injective" can be expressed as

∀x ∀y (f(x) = f(y) → x = y),

the universe of quantification being the set of real numbers R.

How do you propose to eliminate this use of the equality symbol?

If your solution is to have a predicate Y(x) for each variable y to express "y=x", observe that such predicates would *not* behave like ordinary unary predicates. In particular, for an ordinary unary predicate P(x) the proposition "P(x)" and "∀y P(x)" are equivalent, but not so for Y(x). This indicates that "Y(x)" must be treated as a *binary* predicate, and you end up with a binary equality predicate "Eq(x,y)" anyway.

In other words, yes, in the simplest kinds of sentences which consist of nothing but an equality and two constant terms, you can instead of saying "t=u" get by with adding a unary predicate T for each term t and say "T(u)". However, as soon as quantification enters the picture (and quantification is very much the point of doing first-order logic in the first place), this approach falls apart.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning for Y(x) being binary. Presumably "have a predicate Y(x) for each variable y" means that you have a large number of Y_y(x) predicates, one for each y - and not that you have a 'generic' Y(x) that changes definition as you work. In that case Y_y(x) is unary, as it is fixed to its specific y, and only depends on the single input variable.

Comment: Yes, I intended to indicate the relation between the variable y and the "unary predicate" Y by the lower-case vs. upper-case relation, just like with the term t and the predicate T. Of course, you could also indicate it by writing, say E_y(x). My point is that E_y(x) is not a unary predicate (a predicate containing only the variable x) because it does not behave like unary predicates (predicates containing only the variable x) under quantification.

Comment: Does it not? A specific predicate (e.g. Y_10(x), defined as "x is 10") behaves like a unary predicate under quantification (Y_10(x) is equivalent to ∀y Y_10(x)). We are simply defining one of these for each y, each of which behave unary under quantification.

Comment: @Birjolaxew I explain it the answer why E_y(x) does not behave like a unary predicate P(x) if y is a variable: namely, ∀y P(x) is equivalent to P(x0, but ∀y E_y(x) is not equivalent to E_y(x). This shows that E_y(x) needs to be treated as a binary predicate Eq(y,x) where the variable y also occurs free. As you say, E_10(x) is a unary predicate, but that's a different matter.

Comment: It is your explanation in the answer that I am not following. You seem to be using the term "Y(x)" for the binary predicate Y(x,y), where y is not fixed - but I believe OP is asking about the specific implementation Y_y(x) (i.e. why can't we just define E_1(x), E_2(x), E_3(x), ..., if y ∈ ℤ⁺). I cannot see how your argument applies to the latter.

Comment: @Birjolaxew You are right, I see that I may have been answering a different question than the one the OP asked. I was assuming that the OP was asking "why do we need an identity predicate in first-order logic", but re-reading their post, it seems like they may only be asking about very simple sentences of the form t=u, where t and u are constant terms (like "Mark Twain" and "S. L. Clemens"). I will leave it to the OP clarify whether they are asking "do we need an equality predicate in first-order logic" or "can we alternatively treat these simple equality sentences using unary predicates".

Comment: @Adam Prenosil, apologies for the confusion. I think I may have been asking both questions, i.e. why is the identity predicate reqquired in a case like "Mark Twain is Samuel Clemens"?

Comment: This is actually just one of several examples given (see [here](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=wlL2GHt1gS8C&pg=PA298&lpg=PA298&dq=%22none+of+these+can+be+translated+adequately+into+gpl%22&source=bl&ots=ZzrIDU13gV&sig=ACfU3U1huX41mCQba6XHenmqFd_rmV5YVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj26sauv7-CAxXgUWwGHQE1Aj4Q6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22none%20of%20these%20can%20be%20translated%20adequately%20into%20gpl%22&f=false)) of propositions that the book says cannot be adequately translated into GPL.

Comment: I wanted to verify this for myself, so I tried translating them and found that it was in fact not possible to translate the last two into GPL, but this was not as clear cut for the first, second and third examples. E.g. for the first example, "Alice is the tallest person," couldn't we set up a glossary: `Px: x is a person; Ax: x is Alice; Txy: x is taller than y`, and then translate as `∀x∀y((Px ∧ Ax) → Txy)`?

Comment: @user51462 If by "taller" you mean "at least as tall as" (non-strict inequality) and if you allow for more than one tallest person of the same height, i.e. if your interpretation of the sentence is "Alice is one of the tallest people", then sure, that works. Generally "the tallest person" is understood as "strictly taller than everyone else" though.

Comment: Ah true, `Tx` would have to express "x is taller or the same height as y", because Alice cannot be taller than herself. Then, maybe `∀x∀y((Px ∧ Ax ∧ ¬Ay) → Txy)`? That seems clunky though and I'm not sure if it's a faithful translation of the original proposition.

Comment: Also, I have the same question as @Birjolaxew re the example in your post. My post was asking why we couldn't just create a predicate for each *name* in language fragment, not each *variable*. So, if all the `y`'s in our domain had names (e.g. `y1, y2, ..., yn`), then we could create the predicates `Y_1(x): x is y1, ... Y_n(x): x is yn`, and `Y_i(x)` would be equivalent to `∀xY_i(x)` for each `1 <= i <= n`.

Comment: But the `y`s in your example (and most cases in practice) are anonymous, so the language fragment in this case contains *no names* and therefore, it is not possible to create a predicate for each `y`. So, I still like the the example because it shows that cases where the objects are anonymous, we really cannot get away from using the identity predicate (I can't think of any way of expressing injectivity in plain GPL).

Comment: @user51462 Yes, the equality predicate is definable if you fix a universe of quantification where you have finitely many objects and each is designated by a constant term t_1, ..., t_n. Namely, x = y is definable as the disjunction (T_1(x) ^ T_1(y)) v ... v (T_n(x) ^ T_n(y)), where T_i(x) is the unary predicate interpreted as x = t_i.